# Definition of water Plasticization

Tags: organic-chemistry, water

Can someone explain what is water plasticization? I tried to look for the definition but could not find one that explains it.

Comment: Is that term used in the scope of polymers? If so, it is "regular" plasticization, with water as the plasticizer.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticizer),

> **Plasticizers** (UK: **plasticisers**) or **dispersants** are additives that increase the [plasticity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticity_(physics)) or decrease the [viscosity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) of a material.

As far as most research papers say, water is not plasticized, but rather it acts as a plasticizing agent for other substances such as starch films as mentioned in [this article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-2621.2000.tb16025.x). Water makes these films permanently deformed upon external stress and resists reverting back to its original shape.